# Jquery menu not working? button click slideDown

Tags: jquery

```
$('btn').click(function() {
    $('Menu').slideDown();
    }, function() {
        $('btn').click(function(){
          $('Menu').slideUp();
});

});
```

All I want to achieve is, when btn is clicked slideDown menu. when clicked again close!

Answer (score 1):

First, it appears that you're not properly selecting the `btn` and `Menu` elements. You'll need to specify whether they are Classes or IDs.

For instance, using `$('.btn')` or `$('#btn')`. Same must be done for `Menu`.

To simplify your code, try using `slideToggle()`.

```
$('btn').click(function() {
   $('Menu').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/RMS9s/1/)

**UPDATE**

Just for kicks, if you would prefer to use both `slideUp` and `slideDown` events as your comment is requesting, you can achieve this using the `.is(':visible')` functionality:

```
$('#btn').click(function() {
    if ($('#menu').is(":visible")) {
        $('#menu').slideUp('slow');
    }
    else {
        $('#menu').slideDown('slow');
    }  
});
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/RMS9s/)

Comment: Im new to jquery so sorry for such a basic question. How would you achieve the same result with slide Up and down.

Comment: @AndrewJohn slideToggle will take care of that for you. If the element is up, it will slideDown. If the element is down, it will slideUp. In my opinion, this is good practice to use slideToggle in this scenario, but I'll demonstrate how

Answer (score 0):

What are `btn` and `Menu` are they id or classes? Or [other](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)?

To show/hide elements by toggling there is the [`slideToggle`](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) method.

Ref:

> The .slideToggle() method animates the height of the matched elements.
>   This causes lower parts of the page to slide up or down, appearing to
>   reveal or conceal the items. If the element is initially displayed, it
>   will be hidden; if hidden, it will be shown. The display property is
>   saved and restored as needed. If an element has a display value of
>   inline, then is hidden and shown, it will once again be displayed
>   inline. When the height reaches 0 after a hiding animation, the
>   display style property is set to none to ensure that the element no
>   longer affects the layout of the page.
>
> Durations are given in milliseconds; higher values indicate slower
>   animations, not faster ones. The strings 'fast' and 'slow' can be
>   supplied to indicate durations of 200 and 600 milliseconds,
>   respectively.

Code:

```
$('.btn').click(function() {
    $('#menu').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/HHvjC/